# variable insert to a blink function

Tags: html, ajax

I'm new to HTML and ajax. I'm trying to insert a ip list from flask , to the ajax and trigger the js function to blink.
but somehow I can't find a way to insert the ip variable (response[i]) into the function value column in a right way.
it is to trigger the blink on the required ip tab in html.

```
  function ajaxForm(){
          // var form= new FormData(document.getElementById("myform2"));
        var data = {"name":"John Doe"}
          $.ajax({
              url:"{{ url_for('Submit_form') }}",
              type:"post",
              contentType:'application/json',
              data:JSON.stringify(data),
              dataType: "json",
              processData:false,
              // async: false
              success:function(response){
                      // alert(response)
                       if (response == "success")
                           {alert("Success !!!" );}
                       else {
                         for(i in response)
                         {
                           BLINK(response[i]);

                         }
                        }
              },
              // #time out 也进入 error
              error:function(e){
                // alert(e.)
                  alert("Failed submit form trigger!!!!");

              }
          })
        }
```

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function BLINK(){
  var t = null;
  function blink() {
      var obj = $('input[id="IP"][value=response[i]]') . <---- here
      obj.addClass("blink-class");
      t = setTimeout(function () {
          obj.removeClass("blink-class");
          t = setTimeout(function () {
              blink(IP);
          }, 550);
      }, 550);
  }
  blink(IP);
  t = setTimeout(function () {
      clearTimeout(t);
  }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you shoul always provide the HTML code too :) because now we dont know if the issue is there.

So let's try to solve the problem blindly :)

if i see this correctly, you just go wrong on the element and make it even more complicated than it is since you're using jquery, because if u have an ID on your elem, check this out:

```
// change this:
var obj = $('input[id="IP"][value=response[i]]') . <---- here // .. is your problem :)
  obj.addClass("blink-class");
// with the dot you add this obj, which is it self, on it self :) that cant work :)

// you can try:
var obj = $('input[value="' + response[i] + '"]') // with NO dot and no fixed ID!
  obj.addClass("blink-class");

// or try this
var obj = $('#' + response[i]);
obj.addClass("blink-class");
// and put the IP into the ID attraktion of your input element.
```

Second Problem is you are using an undefined variable "ID":

```
blink(IP); // in your timeout function
```

but you didnt declare this var, so if i understand your code right then your response[i] should be the IP?

Your function should look like this:

```
 function BLINK(IP) { // <-- here you need the ip as parameter for your: BLINK(response[i]) from ajax

  var t = null;

  function blink() {

      var obj = $('#' + IP) // and put IP in the id from input

      obj.addClass("blink-class")

      t = setTimeout(function () {
          obj.removeClass("blink-class");
              t = setTimeout(function () {
              blink(IP);
          }, 550);
      }, 550);

  }

  blink(IP);
  t = setTimeout(function () {
      clearTimeout(t);
  }, 5000);
}
```

try this, if its doesnt work please provide complete html and your css code too, also we could need an eventually error message from console, you can see that by pressing F12 in FireFox or Chrome and then switch to the console tab, press F5 then to reload the page and see errors, post it too please.

Or try out my jsfiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/AIQIA/tjg659sr/17/

You have to remove dots from your IP and put it as id in your elem you wants get to blink, further you need to remove the dots from the response[i] or in your php code before, easy use `$ip = preg_replace('/\./','',$ip);`

Or use this to use only the complete IP in your input value, then you dont need to remove dots:
https://jsfiddle.net/AIQIA/tjg659sr/21/

greetz Toxi